# Sufficient statistics for $\mu_1 - \mu_2$

Tags: self-study, inference, sufficient-statistics

If $ X_1, ..., X_n$ is a random sample from $ X \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma^2)$ and $Y_1,..., Y_n$ is a random sample from $Y \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma^2),$ if the samples are independent and $ \sigma^2$ is known, can we say that $\bar{X}-\bar{Y}$ is sufficient for $\mu_1 - \mu_2$ ?

My guess is that it is true. I thought we could define

$$W_i=X_i-Y_i \sim N(\mu_1 - \mu_2, 2 \sigma^2)$$

n independent random variables and use it to show that $\bar{W} = \bar{X} - \bar{Y} $ is sufficient to the mean. Is that correct?

Thanks

Comment: [We can show](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDifferenceDistribution.html) how the pdf of the difference distribution looks like. Afterwards, use the factorization theorem to prove the sufficiency.

Comment: It's not clear at all to me what it means for a statistic to be "sufficient for" a particular parameter. See my answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76743/sufficient-statistic-for-function-of-parameter/76756#76756). However, it also seems in the definition proposed here that this definition may depend on the parameterization.

Comment: Indeed, the statistic is sufficient when based on the difference sample. But there is no argument for reducing the data to the difference sample.

Comment: Consider the case when $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_{2n}$ are your samples... Then what would a sufficient statistic be? There is no rationale in associating $X_i$ with $Y_i$ since the samples are independent.

Comment: @Xi'an That is true. I should have been more careful there.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a statistic $T(x)$ is sufficient if the conditional distribution $P_\theta(x|T(x))$ does not depend on $\theta$. In addition, a distribution belongs to the curved exponential family if it can be written as $L(x;\theta)=h(x)\exp\left(c(\theta)^TT(x)-A(c(\theta))\right)$, then $T(x)$ is a sufficient statistic according to the [Fisher-Neyman factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Fisher%E2%80%93Neyman_factorization_theorem).

Considering the parameter vector $\theta=(\mu_1,\mu_2)$, the likelihood for $X_1,...,X_n,Y_1,...,Y_m$ can be written as:

$$\begin{aligned}
L(X,Y;\theta)=(2\pi\sigma^2)^{0.5n}\exp\left(-0.5\sum((X_i-\mu_1)/\sigma)^2\right)\cdot (2\pi\sigma^2)^{0.5m}\exp\left(-0.5\sum((Y_i-\mu_2)/\sigma)^2\right)
\\=(2\pi\sigma^2)^{0.5(n+m)}\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum(X_i^2-2\mu_1X_i+\mu_1^2+Y_i^2-2\mu_2Y_i+\mu_2^2) \right)
\\=(2\pi\sigma^2)^{0.5(n+m)}\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\left(\sum(X_i^2+Y_i^2)-2\mu_1\sum X_i-2\mu_2\sum Y_i+n\mu_1^2+m\mu_2^2 \right)\right)\\=(2\pi\sigma^2)^{0.5(n+m)}\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum(X_i^2+Y_i^2)+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}(\mu_1\sum X_i+\mu_2\sum Y_i)-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(n\mu_1^2+m\mu_2^2) \right)
\end{aligned}$$

Let $$h(x,y)=(2\pi\sigma^2)^{0.5(n+m)}\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(\sum(X_i^2+Y_i^2)\right),\quad c(\theta)=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\begin{pmatrix}\mu_1\\\mu_2\end{pmatrix},\quad A(z)=\sigma^2(nz_1^2+mz_2^2)$$

we get that the likelihood can be written as

$$L(X,Y;\theta)=h(x,y)\cdot\exp\left(c(\theta)^T\begin{pmatrix}\sum X\\\sum Y\end{pmatrix} -A(c(\theta)) \right)$$

Hence the statistic $T(X,Y)=\begin{pmatrix}\sum X\\\sum Y\end{pmatrix}$ is sufficient. The function $f(a)=\begin{pmatrix}a_1/n\\a_2/m\end{pmatrix}$ is one-to-one and so $\begin{pmatrix}\bar X\\\bar Y\end{pmatrix}$ is also a sufficient statistic. But this doesn't help us for $\mu_1-\mu_2$ so let's try another parametrization:

$$h(x,y)=(2\pi\sigma^2)^{0.5(n+m)}\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(\sum(X_i^2+Y_i^2)\right),\quad c'(\theta)=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\begin{pmatrix}\mu_1-\mu_2\\\mu_2\end{pmatrix},\quad A'(z)=\sigma^2(nz_1^2+mz_2^2-nz_2(2z_1+z_2))$$

and our likelihood is now

$$L(X,Y;\theta)=h(x,y)\cdot\exp\left(c'(\theta)^T\begin{pmatrix}\sum X-\sum Y\\2\sum Y\end{pmatrix} -A'(c(\theta)) \right)$$

Finally the sufficient statistic for $\mu_1-\mu_2$ is $\begin{pmatrix}\sum X-\sum Y\\2\sum Y\end{pmatrix}$ or its transformation $\begin{pmatrix}\bar X-\bar Y\\\bar Y\end{pmatrix}$.